# Chrome button additional padding

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, padding

Im using Contact Form 7 on my WP site, and I'm experiencing a strange issue with the submit button. Im using the following class for the button:

```
.ctaredbutton

background-color: #EA3939;
border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
color: #FFFFFF !important;
font-family: Proxima Nova,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;
letter-spacing: 0.02em;
padding: 22px 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-left:20px
```

The button displays as expected in Firefox (http://cl.ly/SQ5Y) but there appears to be extra padding in Chrome (http://cl.ly/SPcr). The form is live at 'elitegolfusa.org/apply'

Has anyone seen this before? I've got no idea where the additional top padding has came from?

Comment: Try adding `line-height: 15px;`

Comment: Did you figure it out? Accept an answer if it works for you. Otherwise, people may not answer any future questions you write. It's how we get paid around here - by people accepting our answers (assuming they work)

Comment: Hey Mike - apologies, I'm on UK time and the answers came in around midnight last night so I wasn't around to see them - I'll be able to try it out at lunch today and I'll make sure the correct answer is accepted, otherwise I'll find the correct markup and post it myself. I hate finding a thread with no answer! @MikeBarwick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the padding on the top/bottom altogether and use `line-height`. Set line-height to whatever height you want the button.

```
.ctaredbutton{
    background-color: #EA3939;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    font-family: Proxima Nova,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    line-height:45px; // I added this
    padding: 0 30px; // I changed this
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left:20px
}
```